# Matlab: 3d bar plot over specified axes

Tags: matlab

Hallo SOers:
  After searching for a while, the answer still does show up for my question: 
I have a data file like:

```
x  y     z
10 100   30
10 500   90
10 600   200
30 200   30
90 120   300
90 130   30
90 200   60
```

In matlab, I want to plot z over (x, y), which are not continuous points. The plot point should be a bar.
But plot3() seems do not support 3d bar plot,

 and bar3() seems do not allow me to specify my (x,y) column.

So how to get such sparse bar plot?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the values into a Matrix where each element represents a bar. You set your elements to a value and all other elements to zero.

```
>> x = x./10    %I scaled the x and y values down by factor of 10


x =

     1     1     1     3     9     9     9

>> y = y./10

y =

    10    50    60    20    12    13    20


>> A = zeros(max(x),max(y));       %create Matrix of size 9x20
>> for i = 1:length(x)
A(x(i),y(i)) = z(i);               %populate the Matrix
end
>> bar3(A)
>>
```

I am sure you could make the plot nicer by changing some parameters, but this would be the output.

[image: This would be the output.]

Comment: Great! But the color on the x-y plane is really distracting. It would be nice if it colors only based on the hight of the bars.

Comment: You can change that: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f10-19972.html#f10-22737

Comment: But the problem is my data are mostly located around some large value, if i divide them or substract an offset from them, then in the plot I can not see the original value. Is Matlab intelligent enough to handle this problem?