# plot bar chart with discountinous and repeated data in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

I actually have data:

```
 x   y   z
 2  4   0,494949495
 2  6   0,494949495
 2  8   0,535353535
 2  10  0,585858586
 2  12  0,474747475
 3  4   0,535353535
 3  6   0,494949495
 3  8   0,545454545
 3  10  0,484848485
 3  12  0,474747475
 4  4   0,535353535
 4  6   0,474747475
 4  8   0,434343434
 4  10  0,525252525
 4  12  0,494949495
```

I want to plot these data as bar graph where z represent the height of the bars, but the problem is that I don't know how to deal with x and y axis, the value there are repeated and discontinuous and whenever I try to simply use `bar3` I get the following error:

> Error using matlab.graphics.axis.Axes/set
>   While setting the 'YTick' property of 'Axes':
>
> Value must be a vector of type single or double whose values increase
>
> Error in bar3 (line 74)
>
> set(cax,'ytick',y(:,1));

Comment: Matlab normally uses `.` as a decimal separator. Do you have a custom code or you just copied the data from someplace else?

Comment: Have you tried to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991376/how-to-set-x-and-y-values-when-using-bar3-in-matlab)

Comment: Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178430/matlab-3d-bar-plot-over-specified-axes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to plot the z values at each of the coordinates specified by the x and y columns.

```
xyzData=[2  4   0.494949495;
2  6   0.494949495;
2  8   0.535353535;
2  10  0.585858586;
2  12  0.474747475;
3  4   0.535353535;
3  6   0.494949495;
3  8   0.545454545;
3  10  0.484848485;
3  12  0.474747475;
4  4   0.535353535;
4  6   0.474747475;
4  8   0.434343434;
4  10  0.525252525;
4  12  0.494949495];

Y=NaN(xyzData(end,1),max(xyzData(:,2)));
Y(sub2ind(size(Y),xyzData(:,1),xyzData(:,2)))=xyzData(:,3);
figure;bar3(Y)
```

Output:

[image]